# Jetty authentication JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, authentication, jdbc, jetty

I'm using jetty with BASIC authentication and I need to authenticate my client in my unit tests but I got this :

```
WARN:  AUTH FAILURE: user admin
Failed : HTTP error code : 401
```

I don't understand whats is wrong.

If I use the properties file like this it's works :

**realm.properties**

```
admin: adminpwd,admin,user
```

But if I use the properties file with the informations from my database I got the error 401

**realm.properties**

```
jdbcdriver = org.postgresql.Driver
url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
username = postgres
password = test
usertable = admins_users
usertablekey = id
usertableuserfield = user
usertablepasswordfield = userpdw
roletable = roles
roletablekey = id
roletablerolefield = role_name
userroletable = users_roles
userroletableuserkey = user_id
userroletablerolekey = role_id
cachetime = 300
```

How I can authenticate my client with this file ? And why the users from my database are ignored ?

I launch jetty server like that :

```
private Server server;

@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    server = new Server();

    Connector connector = new SelectChannelConnector();
    connector.setPort(8080);
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { connector });

    WebAppContext webappcontext = new WebAppContext();
    webappcontext.setContextPath("/upload");
    webappcontext.setWar("/home/user/upload.war");

    HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[] { webappcontext,
            new DefaultHandler() });

    server.setHandler(handlers);
    HashUserRealm myrealm = new HashUserRealm("MyRealm",
            "/home/user/realm.properties");
    server.setUserRealms(new UserRealm[] { myrealm });

    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are configuring the JDBCLoginService as mentioned here, right?

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security.html#jdbc-login-service

You can also edit the jetty.xml file and enable the dumpOnServerStart option and you should see a listing of how things are configured, this will ensure you have the right mappings in place.

More on the dump feature here:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-dump-tool.html

Comment: Yes the JDBCLoginService and my database are good. But I'm not using the jetty.xml because this file is not detected in my project. Then I use the web.xml from my web service and the code :

It's possible to enable the dump with the code ?

Comment: how are you launching jetty then? maven plugin?  where is your jdbcloginservice defined?

Comment: jetty6? sheesh, there have been over 150 releases since then and it was EOL'd a long time ago.  Anyway, HashUserRealm loads from a properties file the name/password for users...you need to use the JDBCUserRealm.  And seriously consider updating to jetty 9.

Comment: Wow great ! Thanks a lot Jesse. The JDBCUserRealm works. Yes I'm using jetty7 cause I use the package org.mortbay.jetty and my code doesn't work with the package org.eclipse.jetty. Now i'll try to find how to use my code with jetty9

Comment: number of examples documented here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedded-examples.html

Comment: Is anyone using derby embedded with Jetty JDBCLoginService? Because of the way you have to close down the embedded instance of derby, I'm hesitant to switch to JDBCLoginService.